# How to remove a link option from ld in make file?

Tags: makefile, ld, configure

I'm installing a ROOT class and I ran into an error.

```
caffeinated:libroot-hijing-1.7 sudoankit$ make
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link /usr/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11  -g -O2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/root6/6.06.08/lib/root -R /usr/local/Cellar/root6/6.06.08/lib/root -version-info 1:7:0   -o libTHijing.la -rpath /Users/sudoankit/lib THijing.lo THijingMinBias.lo THijingFlow.lo THijingPara.lo TRanMar.lo ran.lo hijing1.383.lo hipyset1.35.lo THijingDict.lo -lCint -lCore -lTree -lPhysics -lGraf3d -lGraf -lHist -lMatrix -lEG  -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0/6.2.0 -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0/6.2.0/../../.. -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
libtool: link: /usr/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-undefined -Wl,dynamic_lookup -o .libs/libTHijing.1.dylib  .libs/THijing.o .libs/THijingMinBias.o .libs/THijingFlow.o .libs/THijingPara.o .libs/TRanMar.o .libs/ran.o .libs/hijing1.383.o .libs/hipyset1.35.o .libs/THijingDict.o   -L/usr/local/Cellar/root6/6.06.08/lib/root -lCint -lCore -lTree -lPhysics -lGraf3d -lGraf -lHist -lMatrix -lEG -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0/6.2.0 -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0/6.2.0/../../.. -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm  -g -O2   -install_name  /Users/sudoankit/lib/libTHijing.1.dylib -compatibility_version 2 -current_version 2.7 -Wl,-single_module
ld: library not found for -lCint
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [libTHijing.la] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

The solution I found after some time is to remove the `-lCint` library from `ld`. How should I do this? Where is the linking located in the `Makefile`? Or the `configure` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of `filter-out`:

```
A = X Y -lCint Z
B = $(filter-out -lCint, $(A))

all: 
    @echo $(B)
```